# UIBarButtonItem GetEvents returns 0 items on real device

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvm-light, system.reflection

I'm using MVVM Light on a Xamarin.iOS project, I bind the commands to buttons using SetCommand, which calls Type.GetEvent(). When I execute the app on the simulator all works fine, but when I execute the app on a real device (iOS 10.3.3) the SetCommand method fails with the message: "Event not found: Clicked 
Parameter name: eventName".

This only happens with UIBarButtonItem, the UIButtons are correctly binded to the "TouchUpInside" in both environments using SetCommand.

I've tested the _uiBarButton.GetType().GetEvents() and is returning an empty array on the real device.

What can be happening here? Someone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after creating my custom extensions methods as a workaround:

```
public static void SetBarButtonCommand(this UIBarButtonItem button, ICommand command)
{
  SetBarButtonCommand(button, string.Empty, command);
}

public static void SetBarButtonCommand(this UIBarButtonItem button, string eventName, ICommand command)
{
  button.Clicked += (s, args) =>
  {
    if (command.CanExecute(null))
    {
      command.Execute(null);
    }
  };

  button.Enabled = command.CanExecute(null);
  command.CanExecuteChanged += (s, args) =>
  {
    button.Enabled = command.CanExecute(null);
  };
}
```

The issue has gone!! It's very strange because I cleaned and recompiled the project several times before trying this, but now I'm using again the default MVVM Light SetCommand extension methods and all is working fine on real device, very very strange...

### Edited

I've found a good article explaining the issue:

[Solving the event not found](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2015/03/solving-the-event-not-found-issue-in-xamarin-mvvmlight-binding-and-commanding/)